# Json encoding a image link

Tags: php, encoding, json

I have a json encoding problem.

If I print `$r['image']` it prints alright. However if I print encoded json object there is a problem.

```
<?php
    echo 'it prints: '.$r['image'];
    //it prints: http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/90145859.jpg

    $jsonObj = json_encode($r);
    echo 'it prints: '.$jsonObj;
?>
```

```
 {"artist_name":"atlanta rhythm section","track_name":"so into you","image":{"@attributes":{"size":"medium"}}}
```

What is the part `{"@attributes":{"size":"medium"}}`? and why can I not see the image link in that place? What i have to do to see `"image":http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/90145859.jpg` on json object?

`var_dump($r);` is:

```
array(3) {
  ["artist_name"]=>
  string(22) "atlanta rhythm section"
  ["track_name"]=>
  string(11) "so into you"
  ["image"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#12 (1) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["size"]=>
      string(6) "medium"
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried url encoding the parameter `$r['image']` but it has not help.

Comment: what do you want to have printed?

Comment: Can you post `var_dump($r)`?

Comment: @Barmar i have updated the post and write 'var_dump($r)'

Comment: @sinaneker I want to see `"image":http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/90145859.jpg` on json object print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force the type to string by casting it:

`print json_encode(array('image' => (string)$r['image']));`

Result:

`"image":http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/90145859.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

```
//This gives the image

<?php 

//form the array
$data['val']="http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/90145859.jpg";

//encode json
$encode = json_encode($data);

echo $encode;

//decode the json 
$decode = json_decode($encode);

//print the image
echo "<img src='".stripslashes($decode->val)."'>";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think $image is an simplexmlobject. Which contains more information, but does not contain it's body, something is written about that here:

[PHP, json_encode, json_decode of SimpleXML Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505211/php-json-encode-json-decode-of-simplexml-object)

A simple workaround can be

```
<?php
$r['image_url'] = (string) $r['image'];
?>
```

This will force the output, just in the same way you do by echoing the object in a string.

Answer (score 0):

use slashes before encoding json

```
$r['image'] = addslashes ($r['image'] );
 json_encode($r);
```

This might Help